# Is there a point to adding getter methods in standard ES 6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I find myself doing stuff like this subconsciously because I usually write PHP.

```
class Car {
    constructor(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    getEngine() {
        return this.engine;
    }
}
```

But only recently did I realise there might be no real practical point to doing so since there are no access modifiers in javascript anyways; in other words, might as well do `car.engine` instead of `car.getEngine()`

*follow-up*

If there is a point; would you (unit) test the getter method (if so, how) and why/why not?

Comment: Subconsciously* - I'd be rather impressed if you could do that in your sleep. ;)

Comment: You do have real getters and setters since ecmascript 5.1 that you can connect to a local variable instead of object properties and thus keep the backing field unaccessible to external consumers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Why do you have `Car` at all, and not just `{engine: engine}`?

Comment: @Lewis ha, unfortunately, I have yet to reach that skill level

Comment: @FelixKling because Car will at some point contain some application logic. the code I provided is just an example

Comment: @Alex I would argue this is even a motivation **not** to use methods named like `car.getEngine()` since the real getter would be accessed as `car.engine` as well

Comment: I agree, either use real setters/getters or just expose the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, methods like `getEngine` are unnecessary clutter. Just access your properties directly, e.g. as `car.engine`. In JavaScript, all properties are public for a reason.

Should you ever need to add logic to the getter method, or refactor the class so that the `engine` is not directly accessible any more, you can still (and should) just use a transparent getter property:

```
class Car {
    constructor(engine) {
        this._engine = engine;
    }
    get engine() {
        return this._engine; // or anything else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer.

Comment: But you can't implement a setter method without a getter method. so there :(

Comment: @XavitojCheema: You also can implement an accessor property with a setter but no getter. What's the issue?

Comment: my jslint gives out warning/error that I'm implementing a setter method without a getter method, so I always implement a getter method. So maybe it's not a real issue.

Comment: Well JsLint is certainly right about that. If it could detect setter *methods* without corresponding getters, it would probably complain about those as well - it's just bad style.